# Lua on git bash doesn't work, works on CMD windows

Tags: lua, git-bash

So I'm trying to use lua on Windows.
I've installed with the LUA Windows Installer and ended up trying on git bash but the command lua isn't recognized.

I've tested on my CMD since my environment variable are set and it works on CMD.

Can't seem to make it work on Git Bash.

[image: The gitbash output]

[image: Cmd output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the [binaries](https://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/) available at the time (5.3.5) and put everything in a 5.3.5 folder inside my Lua folder.

Renamed lua53 in lua. Changed my PATH environnement variable to be

[image: c:\Program Files 86\Lua\5.3.5]

And voilà

[image: Lua output in 5.3.5]