# stuck at the expo init AwesomeProject with react-native extracting template error

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I set up the development environment referring to the documentation, but can't even get through the first step and create an empty project.

I am on Windows 11, Node 16.15.1, and NPM 8.12.2

I keep getting the following error when trying to init react-ative project with expo init awesomeProject

```
Error downloading and extracting template package: Error: npm exited with non-zero code: 1
× Something went wrong while downloading and extracting the template.

Can't read JSON file: D:\crna\awesomeProject\app.json
└─ Cause: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\crna\awesomeProject\app.json'
```

[image]

Comment: Which terminal are you using? I've found that I have problems unless I am using CMD. Can you try CMD in Admin?

Comment: i was using gitBash. tried CMD it works. But still don't get what is the problem, since I already used GitBash and used to work verry well

Answer (score 0):

Based on our comments this is the answer:

Run CMD as Admin rather than GitBash.

As for why GitBash isn't working, here are a couple of other Stack Overflow answers that might shed some light on your issues. I cannot say why it is not working without more information.

[Answer One.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37202896/commands-working-on-windows-command-line-but-not-in-git-bash-terminal)
[Answer Two.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55042635/lua-on-git-bash-doesnt-work-works-on-cmd-windows)